# Unable to boot Cosmic live with PXE

Tags: mount, live-cd, nfs, pxe, 18.10

I'm trying to boot Cosmic live with PXE server

After mounting live.iso file and copying content to a NFS folder, I make copy of casper/vmlinuz and casper/initrd to a tftp server.

The NFS folder is shared from a trusty server (nfs-kernel-server 1.2.8) with export like this:

```
/home/nfs 192.168.0.0/16(ro,async,no_subtree_check)
```

Here is the PXE config :

```
LABEL cosmic
        MENU LABEL Ubuntu 18.10 x64
        KERNEL cosmic/vmlinuz
        APPEND initrd=cosmic/initrd file=cosmic/ubuntu.seed boot=casper netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.0.3:/home/nfs/cosmic locale=fr_FR bootkbd=fr console-setup/layoutcode=fr
```

Unfortunately, during boot, some mount errors appears and boot process switch to **emergency mode (hit ctrl+d)**.

journalctl -xb show me that errors :

```
Failed to mount Huge Pages File System.
Failed to mount Kernel Debug File system.
Failed to mount POSIX Message Queue File System.
Failed to mount Kernel Configuration File system.
Failed to mount FUSE Control File system.
Failed to mount /tmp.
Failed to start Set console font and keymap.
```

This PXE server boot Bionic, Xenial, Trusty, ... the same way without problem

Answer (score 0):

Just add `systemd.mask=tmp.mount` to your APPEND line and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

"Just add systemd.mask=tmp.mount to your APPEND line and it should work."

This work for me.

After solve this problem, it's occur another problem.
If use source from PXE Server to install OS. 
It's found some failed message.
'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into /target/. Without the GRUB bootloader, the installed system will not boot.
But if use the Ubuntu Mirror via Internet, it finish install OS without failed message.